# How to add multiple tasks to a main coroutine in asyncio3.7?

Tags: python-asyncio

I am trying to update my code from asyncio3.6 to asyncio3.7.
One philosophical element of the transition is that it is strongly encouraged to use a single entry point in your program, in particular a single `asyncio.run(main())`.

This program works:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("hi")

asyncio.run(foo())
```

And this program works:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("hi")

async def main():
    await foo()

asyncio.run(main())
```

But the following program exits with no error before anything is printed:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("hi")

async def bar():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("ho")

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(foo())
    asyncio.create_task(bar())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Is the asyncio3.7 prescribed best practice to have main await a future which is, say, set when some error occurs?

I know that adding some `await future` line to the bottom of main makes the third program "work", but I'm still not happy with the use of `create_task` for the infinite coroutines inside main; the whole point of having a single entry point is that you can catch all unhandled exceptions raised by your program at a single point. But when you have so-called "dangling" tasks like this it doesn't suppress the need to `set_exception_handler` on the loop.

Comment: I think you should await the tasks after having created them, as it shows [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: You have changed the question, as it was malformed then. I am going to remove my answer since it does not seem to apply anymore. Next time make the point of the question more explicit

Comment: yeah I added the last paragraph, thanks @Pynchia

Comment: Just a side note: if you `await` the created tasks, then they're not really dangling! A potential problem with `await task1; await task2` is that if `task2` raises while `task1` is still running, you will not be notified. (In practice the exception might also cause `task1` not to finish because it's waiting forever for something from `task2`, in which case you have a deadlock.) `asyncio.gather()` will by default ensure that the first exception occurring in a task gets propagated to the caller, and (when placed in the top-level coroutine) terminate execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you simply need something like:

```
async def main():
    # wait for both `foo()` and `bar()` to finish
    await asyncio.gather(foo(), bar())
```

You can also use `asyncio.wait(return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)` to wait until *either* `foo()` or `bar()` finishes, but that requires additional care to actually retrieve their results in order to correctly propagate the exceptions.

Awaiting an explicit future is more advanced usage, most appropriate when the decision to exit the program must be made inside a deeply nested callback.